# ERROR: Failed building wheel for pysqlite3

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite

I tried to install pysqlite3 but get following errors:

```
ERROR: Failed building wheel for pysqlite3;
Failed to build pysqlite3;
ERROR: Could not build wheels for pysqlite3, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

I am able to import pysqlite3 and play around with it. Is this error significant or material?

```
H:\>python -m pip install pysqlite3
Collecting pysqlite3
  Using cached pysqlite3-0.5.0.tar.gz (40 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: pysqlite3
  Building wheel for pysqlite3 (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [18 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\pysqlite3
      copying pysqlite3\dbapi2.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\pysqlite3
      copying pysqlite3\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\pysqlite3
      running build_ext
      Builds a C extension linking against libsqlite3 library
      building 'pysqlite3._sqlite3' extension
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release\src
      "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.36.32532\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe" /c /nologo /O2 /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DMODULE_NAME=\"pysqlite3.dbapi2\" -I/usr/include -IC:\Users\xxxx.xxxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\include -IC:\Users\xxxx.xxxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.36.32532\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.36.32532\ATLMFC\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Auxiliary\VS\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22621.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\cppwinrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.7.2\include\um" /Tcsrc\blob.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release\src\blob.obj
      blob.c
      C:\Users\xxxx.xxxx\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-4i2pzz45\pysqlite3_5ac2e34a156748b2b1f34f4cbfcac3b4\src\blob.h(4): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'sqlite3.h': No such file or directory
      error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.36.32532\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pysqlite3
  Running setup.py clean for pysqlite3
Failed to build pysqlite3
ERROR: Could not build wheels for pysqlite3, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

Comment: Found any solution to the above?

Comment: @RohitMittal Nah. But I had a need for it so far....